# Swift - Problem handeling button selection

Tags: swift, button, selection

I have a floating button in my app that display 5 different buttons. Each of them has a color but initially are gray. When the user selects one of the buttons, all of them hide, and when the user taps again on the floating button, the button that was previously tapped is not gray but with its proper color.

Also the logic would be that the user can tap another one of the buttons to select it, and the previous one would be unselected, as if the user taps on a selected button, it gets unselected.

I'm using cocoa pods for the Floating Button, JJFloatingActionButton, but on the documentation there is no info about this.

```
func configureActionButton() {
    actionButton.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    actionButton.buttonImage = UIImage(systemName: "line.horizontal.3.decrease")
    actionButton.buttonColor = UIColor(named: "signoColor")!
    actionButton.buttonImageColor = .white
    actionButton.buttonImageSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    actionButton.itemAnimationConfiguration = .slideIn(withInterItemSpacing: 14)
    actionButton.itemSizeRatio = CGFloat(0.75)

    let item = actionButton.addItem()
    item.titleLabel.text = "Button 1"
    item.buttonColor = UIColor(red: 254/255.0, green: 224/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    item.buttonImageColor = UIColor(red: 200/255.0, green: 73/255.0, blue: 203/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    item.imageSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    item.action = { item in
        //This is for the functionality of the button
    }

    let item2 = actionButton.addItem()
    item2.titleLabel.text = "Button 2"
    item2.buttonColor = UIColor(red: 254/255.0, green: 224/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    item2.buttonImageColor = UIColor(red: 200/255.0, green: 73/255.0, blue: 203/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    item2.imageSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    item2.action = { item in
        //This is for the functionality of the button
    }

    //And I have 3 more buttons
```

}

This is how the floating button looks like:
[image]

I would appreciate some help. I've searched for similar questions but none of them solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up the button's with their initial colours the way you want, rather than with their colours, and then in the action closure check their state and alter apearances accordingly.  Without the detail on what the pod is doing this is all an edcated guess.

Comment: What's the class of `item`? Just make add to it a "selected state", and when you show them, according to its state, make it gray or with its initial color. I guess that the logic of which is the button selected could be in `actionButton`.